# can I somehow view FluentNHibernate automappings?

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've got a table I'm not sure is being mapped correctly.  I tried looking around the source, but couldn't easily find a way to look at the mappings for a particular entity.

Can someone point me to where those are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are automappings and you want to look at what the xml mapping looks like I usually do this by exporting the mappings via xml like so:

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(normalConfig)
                  .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                      .AddFromAssemblyOf<OrderMap>()
                      .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<PascalCaseColumnNameConvention>()
                      .ExportTo(@"C:\TFS\Fluent Mappings"))
                      .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate")
                  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The important part of course is the: `.ExportTo(@"C:\TFS\Fluent Mappings"))` above.

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect.  I ended up exporting to a TextWriter but v useful.